# Running a local script remotely

Tags: bash

I am wonder if there is a way to run a local script on a remote server without copying the local script to the server.

I know I can use scp to copy a script to a server then use ssh to run the script but I am trying to avoid copying the script and all of it's dependencies on the remote host.

Let's say I have localscript.sh on localhost.com and the target host is remotehost.com.

How do you run localscript.sh from the localhost.com and have it execute on the remotehost.com?

Comment: `ssh user@remotehost.com bash<localscript.sh`

Comment: Blue Moon. That works perfect! I'd except that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the script is bash you can invoke the shell on the remote machine and read the script from local machine:

```
ssh user@remotehost.com "bash -s" < localscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh root@remoteServer "bash -s" < /path_to_File/file.sh
```